# How to access a control added from C# by name

Tags: c#, wpf, xamlreader

I have added a content Control containing a telerik Chart which i have named bob.
I have used xamlReader.parse to build the content control and then place it onto a canvas.

I now want to access the the chart called bob to set it's values.

```
var myChart = (RadCartesianChart)this.FindName("bob");
```

I keep receiving null.

Could someone help me identify my chart and show me how to access it?

Code to add ContentControl to a canvas in my Xaml.

```
StringBuilder LineCharString = new StringBuilder("<ContentControl ");
LineCharString.Append("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' ");
LineCharString.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");
LineCharString.Append("xmlns:s='clr-namespace:AccSys.Helpers.Dashboard;assembly=AccSys' ");
LineCharString.Append("xmlns:telerik='http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation' ");
LineCharString.Append("Width='100' Height='100' MinWidth='50' MinHeight='50' Canvas.Top='160' Canvas.Left='30'>");
LineCharString.Append("<Grid IsHitTestVisible='False'>");
LineCharString.Append("<Grid.RenderTransform>");
LineCharString.Append("<TranslateTransform/>");
LineCharString.Append("</Grid.RenderTransform>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name='" + ChartName + "'>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility='XY' MajorXLineDashArray='10,5' MajorXLinesRenderMode='All' />");
LineCharString.Append("</telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:LinearAxis/>");
LineCharString.Append("</telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:CategoricalAxis/>");
LineCharString.Append("</telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>");
LineCharString.Append("<telerik:BarSeries x:Name='xBarSeries' CategoryBinding='XValue' ValueBinding='YValue'/>");
LineCharString.Append("</telerik:RadCartesianChart>");
LineCharString.Append("</Grid>");
LineCharString.Append("</ContentControl>");

ContentControl LineChartCC = new ContentControl();
LineChartCC = (ContentControl)XamlReader.Parse(LineCharString.ToString());

var canvass = DashboardCanvas;
canvass.Children.Add(LineChartCC);
```

Comment: Could you show your XAML also?

Comment: Did you name it when creating it? When being added into the form it will not retain the variable name as its name, it must instead be explicitly set. Also is the Cartesian chart *that* rad?

Comment: @S.Akbari i have shown the C# code that parses the string into xaml

Answer (score 0):

If by 'named' you mean setting XAML property x:Name, you can reach it by this name. For example name="Control" -> Control.SomeProperty = ""